# I get error Unable to find docker image locally; However I can run the image using docker run command

Tags: r, docker, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, docker-image

I built the docker image, tagged it and pushed it using the following commands

```
docker build -t myimage:version1 .
docker tag myimage:version1 gcr.io/my_test_project/myimage:version1
docker push gcr.io/my_test_project/myimage:version1
```

I have been following steps from: https://cloudyr.github.io/googleComputeEngineR/articles/massive-parallel.html

My my_test.R file is as follows:

```
rm(list=ls())
project <- "my_test_project"
zone <- "us-central1-a"
account_key <-"~/my-secret-key.json"

Sys.setenv(GCE_AUTH_FILE = account_key,
           GCE_DEFAULT_PROJECT_ID = project,
           GCE_DEFAULT_ZONE = zone)

library("googleComputeEngineR")
library("future")
library("future.apply")
library("parallel")

gce_global_project(project)
gce_global_zone(zone)

my_docker <- gce_tag_container(container_name="myimage:version1")

vm_base_name <- "vm-base-00"
cluster_size = 3
vm_names <- paste0(vm_base_name, seq(1,cluster_size))

vms <- gce_vm_cluster(vm_prefix=vm_base_name,
                      cluster_size=cluster_size,
                      docker_image = my_docker,
                      ssh_args = list(username="test_user",
                      key.pub="/home/test_user/.ssh/google_compute_engine.pub", 
                      key.private="/home/test_user/.ssh/google_compute_engine"),
                      predefined_type = "n1-highmem-2")

plan(strategy="cluster", workers = as.cluster(vms, docker_image=my_docker))

gce_vm_stop(vms)
gce_vm_delete(vms)
```

I get the following error:

```
Unable to find image 'gcr.io/my_test_project/myimage:version1' locally
/usr/bin/docker: Error response from daemon: unauthorized: You don't have the needed permissions to perform this operation, and you may have invalid credentials. To authenticate your request, follow the steps in: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication.
See '/usr/bin/docker run --help'.
```

I did debug the code:
The line `plan(strategy="cluster", workers = as.cluster(vms, docker_image=my_docker))` triggers the error.

**Notes:**

1. I can run the docker image locally without any issues
2. `docker images` command contains the list of image I am trying to work on.
3. My container visibility is Private on https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/settings, and I intend to keep it that way. (I can run the code when I make it public -- I still get 'unable to find image locally warning', but it pulls the image from gcloud)

**Additional Notes:**
command `gsutil iam get gs://artifacts.my_test_project.appspot.com/` gives the following

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "members": [
        "user:test_user@example.com"
      ],
      "role": "roles/storage.legacyBucketOwner"
    },
    {
      "members": [
        "user:test_user@example.com"
      ],
      "role": "roles/storage.legacyBucketReader"
    },
    {
      "members": [
        "user:test_user@example.com"
      ],
      "role": "roles/storage.legacyObjectReader"
    },
    {
      "members": [
        "user:test_user@example.com"
      ],
      "role": "roles/storage.objectViewer"
    }
  ],
  "etag": "CBQ="
}
```

Comment: Just to make sure, have you installed the `future` package in your image by including it as part of your Dockerfile?

Comment: Yes, it is included

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the VM cluster instances created did not have the .docker/config.json file in them. Hence the docker image could not be pulled by the VMs, resulting in the error.
One way to resolve this is to SSH into the VMs and run the `docker-credential-gcr configure-docker` command. This generates the `.docker/config.json` folder/file successfully allowing the VMs to pull the images.

Answer (score 1):

The service account that is used to authenticate API calls from your GCE instances doesn't seem to have proper permissions to access the Container Registry. I'd say this is the service account represented by the `my-secret-key.json` you set as environment variable.

You may want to add the proper permissions to that service account, in particular the `roles/storage.objectViewer` role (see the doc [here](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control) for more details) so that it can pull the image.

Comment: Thank you! I reconfigured the permissions and restarted the session.

Comment: I added the permissions I currently have under "Additional Notes". Still getting the same error.